# Algorithm better than O(nlgn) for josephus problem to print killed person in order

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

My problem base on [the josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), I want to print the position of killed people one by one in order.

> People are standing in a circle waiting to be executed. Counting begins at a specified point in the circle and proceeds around the circle in a specified direction. After a specified number of people are skipped, the next person is executed. The procedure is repeated with the remaining people, starting with the next person, going in the same direction and skipping the same number of people, until only one person remains, and is freed.
>
> The problem — given the number of people, starting point, direction, and number to be skipped — is to choose the position in the initial circle to avoid execution.

Below is an example using self-balancing BST that runs in `O(nlg(n))`

```
def simulate(n, m):
    # all index from 0
    people = SortedList(range(n))
    idx = 0
    while len(people)>1:
        idx = (idx+m-1)%len(people)
        yield people.pop(idx)
```

I wonder whether there is a better algorithm than `O(nlg(n))`. If not, how to prove.